# Apache web server error; time taking too long to access

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, webserver, virtualbox

I am currently trying to redirect to my Apache Web Server from the CentOS virtual environment using VirtualBox by following the tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-centos-7

I believe I have everything set up, but when I try to access the apache web server (which it is running btw), Chrome gives me a `took too long to respond.` error.

I typed in `ip addr show` in the command prompt and [image]

the following result showed; I am assuming that my IP address is `10.0.2.15/24`, but accessing `http://10.0.2.15/24` again, does not work.

I also tried accessing `127.0.0.1/8` but that doesn't give me anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Please advise.

UPDATE:
This is the content of my /var/log/httpd directory. [image]

UDPATE:
This is the content of my error_log. I highlighted a possible error that might be causing the issue. The access_log by the way was empty.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I realized that the URL was not correct. Instead of accessing http://10.0.2.15, I accessed http://*my_host_name_that_I_set_up_during_installation*:80 and I was able to access the apache welcome page.

Answer (score 0):

try accessing http://10.0.2.15
it is not http://10.0.2.15/24

regards,
Yuyanto

Comment: @Yuyanto thank you for your response. I tried to access it but it does not work. It also gives me a too long to respond error

Comment: please check the logs file ini /var/log/httpd/.. maybe you can get any clue.. or can paste here and we can check together

Comment: thank you! I've added a snapshot of the /var/log/httpd directory. I just literally started learning this yesterday so I'm not sure which file to check.

Comment: please cd into httpd directory and check the access.log and error.log file

Comment: I have updated my question. Could not determine server's domain name was found inside the error_log.

Comment: Actually, I was able to access the server by typing in http://myhostname:80. Not sure why this worked though.